# I can't get the item to go into the next slot for my Unity game

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I've been following along with this tutorial on how to Create a survival game in Unity Part 2. I am stuck trying to get the item to be added to another slot once the first slot is full. Using C#. Here is a timestamp link to the video I'm following https://youtu.be/1sO-BbK4bIY?t=1750

My Inventory.CS file

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Inventory : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject inventory;
    public GameObject slotHolder;
    private bool inventoryEnabled;

    private int slots;
    private Transform[] slot;

    private GameObject itemPickedUp;
    private bool itemAdded;

    public void Start()
    {
        // slots being detected
        slots = slotHolder.transform.childCount;
        slot = new Transform[slots];
        DetectInventorySlots();
    }

    public void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.I))
        {
            inventoryEnabled = !inventoryEnabled;
        }

        if (inventoryEnabled)
            inventory.SetActive(true);
        else
            inventory.SetActive(false);

        
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Item")
        {
            itemPickedUp = other.gameObject;
            AddItem(itemPickedUp);
        }
    }

    public void OnTriggerExist(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Item")
        {
            itemAdded = false;
        }
    }

    public void AddItem(GameObject item)
    {

        for (int i = 0; i < slots; i++)
        {
            if (slot[i].GetComponent<Slot>().empty && itemAdded == false)
            {
                slot[i].GetComponent<Slot>().item = itemPickedUp;
                slot[i].GetComponent<Slot>().itemIcon = itemPickedUp.GetComponent<Item>().icon;
                itemAdded = true;

            }
        }
    }

    public void DetectInventorySlots()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < slots; i++)
        {
            slot[i] = slotHolder.transform.GetChild(i);

        }
    }
}
```

My Slot.CS File

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class Slot : MonoBehaviour, IPointerEnterHandler, IPointerExitHandler
{

    private bool hovered;
    public bool empty;


    public GameObject item;
    public Texture itemIcon;

    void Strart()
    {

        hovered = false;
    
    }

    void Update()
    {

        if (item)
        {
            empty = false;

            itemIcon = item.GetComponent<Item>().icon;
            this.GetComponent<RawImage>().texture = itemIcon;

        }
        else
        {
            empty = true;
        }

    }

    public void OnPointerEnter(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        hovered = true;
    }

    public void OnPointerExit(PointerEventData eventData)
    {
        hovered = false;
    }
}
```

And my Item.CS file

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Item : MonoBehaviour
{
    
    
    public Texture icon;
        

}
```

Comment: Why not use Get Set instead of checking Update all time to catch the item. If you call this each frame your setting first empty to false and can insert again in the same slot. If not move to GetSet option add another bool to control it "adding" to not join multiple times on the condition.